# why does this property return undefined?

Tags: javascript, audio, codec

I'm working on an AMR codec in Javascript and i cannot seem to get a file reference to be recognized by the decoder module. Here is a sample of my code:

```
 reader.onload = (function (file) {
        return function (e) {

            var extension = file.name.split(".")[1];

            if (extension === "amr") {
                console.log("in try");
                var stuff = e.target.result;
                console.log(stuff.length);
                var jigg = new AMR();
                jigg.benchmark == 'true';
                console.log(jigg); //jigg is defined, it's an instance of amr
                // let's call some amr functions...
                var dcoded = jigg.decode(stuff);

                AMR.util.play(dcoded); //this throws an 'undefined' error, indicating that 'dcoded' is undefined. 


            } else if (extension == "wav") {
                var data = e.target.result;
                encodeWAV(data);
            } else if (extension == "pcm" && isTypedArray) {
                encodeRawPCM(new Int16Array(e.target.result));
            }
        };
    })(f);

    if ( !! isTypedArray) {
        reader.readAsArraybuffer(f);
        return;
    }
    // Read the file as a Binary String
    reader.readAsBinaryString(f);
}
```

I have commented the line where the trouble occurs.

```
 AMR.util.play(dcoded);
```

Comment: Can you post the exact error message? From your comment it looks like `jigg.decode(stuff)` returned `undefined`.

Comment: It seems like `jigg.decode(stuff);` doesn't work on `stuff`. What does `console.out(stuff);` say?

Comment: if you have a significant amount of code you should think about unit-testing it first ,and post the relevant code too we cant guess what jigg.decode do exactly.

Comment: wow, thanks! console.log(stuff) prints: "stscÁstco".

Comment: I'm trying to break the program down and unit test. Check out my JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/trkkazulu/T9JWD/2/embedded/result/

Comment: I'm not using the "Activate" button. Forget that. The big problem is that when i call "decode", that function makes a call to a function that assesses the length property of my var "dcoded". This "mystery" function is hidden in a lib that i'm using. I don't have the src for the lib only a min version of it. I'm not sure how to debug that.